# Сохранить элемент в переменную и работать с ним далее

Tags: jquery

Есть функция обработчик клика по чекбоксу.

```
$('#owner').on('click', function() {
    var fieldset = $(this).next().next(),
        required = fieldset.find('input[type="text"].required');
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        fieldset.fadeOut();
        required.removeClass('required');
        fieldset.find('input[type="text"]').val('');
    } else {
        fieldset.fadeIn();
        required.addClass('required');
    }

});
```

Суть вопроса в следующем, как мне не потерять доступ к элементу по класу`.required`, когда я первый раз этот класс удаляю. Я думал что сохранив элементы в переменную раз я смогу манипулировать ими в будущем, а выходит фрагмент `required = fieldset.find('input[type="text"].required');` ищет по данному классу всегда по новому. И удалив этот класс один раз я уже к этим элементам не "достучусь".

Comment: У вас переменная объявлена внутри области видимости коллбека. Попробуйте вынести её наружу `var foo; $(function(){foo = 123});`

Comment: а зачем ты удаляешь или добавляешь этот класс?

Comment: Я думал об этом, однако филдсет там не один, и я привязываю поиск нужного к this. Тоесть за пределами функции тяжело будет найти нужный... Можно сделать костылями с добавлением классов, но я хотел бы узнать есть ли способ сделать все "чисто".

Comment: @Grundy Нажимаем на чекбокс, скрывается филдсет, а поля с этим класом обязательные, когда они скрыты то не могут быть обязательными, и наоборот, надеюсь ты понял суть.

Answer (score 1):

Отож :).

В таких случаях надо иметь еще один класс, даже если он ни в каких стилях не описан:

```
<input class="may-be-required required" type="text"/>

required = fieldset.find('input[type="text"].may-be-required');
```

Comment: Спасибо, думал об этом, но хотелось бы знать существует ли еще изощреннее способ) Чтоб воще не подкопаться)) Чтоб без лишних класов, просто сохранить эти элементы в переменную и работать с ними в свое удовольствие)

Comment: Объясните, что значит "воще не подкопаться". Кто хочет под Вас подкопаться? Это правильный способ. Что Вам в нем не нравится?

Comment: В общем, я б так и сделал как Вы предлагаете, но я сюда написал для опыта в будущем, чтоб знать можно ли такое провернуть. Сохранить эти элементы в переменную и работать с ними далее без оглядки.

Comment: Потому что лично для меня такое поведение jquery стало новостью, я думал что все будет работать, и был удивлен)) Зеленый еще))

Comment: Какое поведение стало новостью? Что после удаления класса, элементы по этому классу не находятся?

Comment: Я думал они находяться раз, и потом добавляй классы, удаляй, в переменной будут все те элементы которые я туда сохранил ранее. Теперь понял что это не так.

Comment: Вы присваиваете `required` (т.е. ищете элементы) каждый раз, когда вызывается обработчик клика.

Comment: И это правильно, так как в их поиске участвует `this`.

Comment: Спасибо, я чет влоще уже заблудился во всем этом)) Но Вы меня натолкнули на мысль)) Я решыл задачу) Ща отвечу на свой вопрос)

Answer (score 0):

Значит, всем спасибо, особенно господину @Igor, я нашел способ. Возможно это жуткий костыль, и способ предложенный Igor был более правильный, но все же. Я добавил флаг `flag`

```
var required,
    flag = 0;
$('#owner').on('click', function() {
    var fieldset = $(this).next().next();
        if (flag == 0) {
            required = fieldset.find('input[type="text"].required');
            flag = 1;
        }
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        fieldset.fadeOut();
        required.removeClass('required');
        fieldset.find('input[type="text"]').val('');
    } else {
        fieldset.fadeIn();
        required.addClass('required');
    }

});
```

Таким образом переменная `required` назначается только при первом клике на чекбокс, а при остальных игнорируется))

Comment: это не сработает с несколькими fieldset, ты всегда будешь хранить required, для первого fieldset

Comment: Не делайте так, это плохое решение :(. `<сарказм>`Зачем Вы, в таком случае, ищите `fieldset` каждый раз? Сохраняйте и его во внешнюю переменую.`</сарказм>`